# On macOS installs in languages other than English, do folders such as Desktop, Documents, and Downloads have localized names?

Tags: internationalization, language

I always set up my mac to use (Australian) English but if I installed it choosing a different language, would that change the names of the user folders such as `Desktop`, `Documents`, `Downloads`, etc?

And if so, would the localized names only appear in GUI apps such as Finder, or would they also be localized at the low filesystem level, as you'd see by doing `ls ~` in Terminal?

What about just having multiple users on a single Mac? Does each user get to choose their language and have that affect the names of their user folders, or is that only determined by the "master" language/locale setting done during OS install time?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

They are only localized in the GUI.

---

Quick example with German as the system language:

The folder for Swift Playgrounds shows

> Macintosh HD → Benutzer:innen → myusername → Dokumente

But if I do control+click, select copy and then paste it into textedit it says

> /Users/myusername/Documents

Comment: And interesting thing is, if you happen to remove one of those folders (like I managed to do with `Downloads` once) even if you restore it back — it will get the proper icon, but the name will stay in English, as it is named in the folder path.

Comment: @user28434 That would almost certainly be because your newly-created folder(s) do not contain the same data in the resource fork and/or extended attributes that allow the Finder to recognize them as user-level folders and display them with localized names. You would need to take extra steps to copy or otherwise reproduce this additional metadata when creating new folders.

Comment: @CodyGray, yeah, `kMDItemDisplayName`and/or `_kMDItemDisplayNameWithExtensions` to be specific

Comment: @CodyGray: Note that folders do not have resource forks.

Answer (score 4):

If you're using Australian English, you'll be able to see the folder called `~/.Trash` in the Terminal, which in the Finder GUI is called the "Bin" (but in American English called "Trash").

Comment: Interesting. Though if I do `open ~/.Trash` from the Terminal I get a Finder window showing what would otherwise be a hidden folder labelled `Delete` rather than either `Bin` or `Trash`.

Comment: @hippietrail Yes, the "Trash" GUI concept is more than one folder: it's several different `.Trash` folders in different places. But it still answers your question. The localization to Bin only came in the last couple of years.

Comment: Not to be confused with the various system-level directories where "bin" is short for "binary"...

Answer (score 2):

In MacOS, files or folders have a Posix name, and they can have one or several localised names. The localised name is what is used in the GUI. So you have an "Applications" folder. Lots of code would fail if that folder ever changed its name. However, the names that users see can be different. So a French, Italian or Greek user would see a different name.

Note: The localised names are stored in “file attributes”. There are functions to read or write these attributes, so you can localise the names of your own files. If you write code to copy a file by reading the source and writing it to the destination file, that’s not going to copy these attributes. There are functions that copy files exactly as the Finder would, together with all attributes.